# Bash shell - Sort a list of words by the second letter?

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

I need to sort a list of words alphabetically by the second letter and I can't seem to figure out a way to do it.

Unsorted:

```
smokelessly
toelike
arsenous
malabar
antiperspirant
hock
nibbing
paleographically
goon
```

Sorted:

```
malabar
paleographically
nibbing
smokelessly
antiperspirant
hock
toelike
goon
arsenous
```

I've read about the `sort` command but it doesn't seem to have the functionality to let me do this?

Comment: is this data in a file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sort -kX.Y` is your friend! `X` refers to the column and `Y` to the character.

```
$ sort -k1.2 file
malabar
paleographically
nibbing
smokelessly
antiperspirant
hock
toelike
goon
arsenous
```

If you want to define the last position to sort from, you can use

```
sort -k1.2,Z file
```

---

From `man sort`:

> **-k**, --key=KEYDEF
>
> sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
>
> KEYDEF  is  F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]]  for  start  and stop position,
>   where F is a field number and C a character position in the field;
>   both are origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end. 
>   If neither -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a field are counted
>   from the beginning of the preceding whitespace.  OPTS is one or more
>   single-letter ordering options [bdfgiMhnRrV], which override global
>   ordering options for that key.  If no key is given, use the entire
>   line as the key.

Comment: Ahh. Don't you just love GNU software?